# Customized Slider (JavaFX)

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

I have a slider in javaFX that is binded with a timeline and shows from 0 to 10 minutes the current time.
The problem comes when I redraw the slider to my needs ( dynamically changing the time) so if I load something it can have instead of the default times something like from 0 to 3 minutes, or from 0 to 3 minutes and 31 seconds. Then here comes my question:

Could I set the majorTicks and minorTicks somehow that it shows me the intermediary values and the final value. For now it can show me the 0---10s--20s...-1min-...2min-..3min-...blank. Where the 's' things are the minorTicks and 1min,2min are the majorTicks and the blank is the problem. The blank is this 3min and 31s that is not shown, it's just empty.

Do you know what algorithm should I apply to make this working?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here are the screenshots:[normal-slider](http://prntscr.com/2xcra6)

[when I have more than 60 minutes](http://prntscr.com/2xctjo)

Comment: Visualizing the description of the problem could be more helpful.

Comment: now I'm short on time, but I will put one soon. Thanks for reply!

Comment: added the screen shots

Comment: I suggest to disable the majorTicks and majorTicks at all, and show the slider without tick. The changing time will be shown as text. Also check the http://jfxtras.org/ gadgets out for other ideas. You will see there a calendar-time picker.

Comment: First thanks for reply! Yes I knew about the jfxtras project, the thing about that picker is that they use two pickers: one for hours and one for minutes. That will not work for my project. I need just an algorithm to change when I have over 60 min in hours. I tried something, but the solution managed to screw my slider-timeline binding.